# SQL - If both only

Tags: sql

I am trying to follow some queries I have to meet for an assignment, and one has got me stuck and have researched many ways to do it but not getting anywhere.

The query I am trying to meet is;

"List all pizza's with the toppings Olive's and Pepperoni"

This is not asking for all pizza's with olive's and all pizza's with pepperoni, but **both**.

I have managed to get it to list all pizza's which have either, however if I chuck an AND in there, it simply concatenates the ID's together.

Here are my tables;

```
ToppingID   ToppingDesc 
    20      Cheese
    21      Tomato
    22      Pepperoni
    23      Ground-Beef
    24      Meatballs
    25      Chicken
    26      Peppers
    27      Onion
    28      Mushroom
    29      Ham
    30      Pineapple
    31      Olives
    32      Anchovies
    33      Sweetcorn
```

So here you can see that Pepperoni is 22, Olives are 31

```
PizzaID     ToppingID
  90            22
  92            31
  95            22
  95            31
  96            31
  98            31
```

Here we can see that 95 occur's twice cause it contains **both**.

```
PizzaID     CrustID
  90          801
  92          802
  95          801
  96          801
  98          802
```

With my statment I'd Ideally like this to be displayed

```
PizzaID     ToppingID
  95           22
  95           31
```

But from all the queries I run, I just get a result of the table above displaying all pizza's with either of them.

Is it possible to get it to display just **both** on one pizza ?
When I use an and it looks for a ToppingID of '3122'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show your table definitions, and what queries you've tried please?

Comment: Also, what RDBMS?  This is likely a duplicate of any number of questions, but the answers could be dependent on the database you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Pizzas p
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT PizzaID FROM PizzaToppings WHERE ToppingID = 22 AND PizzaID = p.PizzaID)
  AND EXISTS
  (SELECT PizzaID FROM PizzaToppings WHERE ToppingID = 31 AND PizzaID = p.PizzaID)
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm being dumb? But when I used this I got the error;
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Pizzas'.

Comment: Well, you didn't specify the names of your tables so I guessed.

Comment: My bad, I added in the correct table names and it worked! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to do this that should work across most databases.

As you forgot to mention what your tables are named I'm using the name PizzaToppings for the junction table between pizza and toppings.

```
select * from PizzaToppings 
where PizzaID in (
    select PizzaID from PizzaToppings where ToppingID = 22
    intersect -- this is sometimes known by other names
    select PizzaID from PizzaToppings where ToppingID = 31
)

select * from PizzaToppings 
where PizzaID in (
    select PizzaID from PizzaToppings where ToppingID in (22,31)
    group by PizzaID having COUNT(ToppingID) = 2
)
```

Comment: I like the first solution.  My only problem with the second solution is that you may get false positives if a pizza has two Pepperoni toppings.  There may be data integrity rules in place to prevent that, but in general I don't like to rely on counts to match multiple criteria.

Comment: @DStanley Yeah, I'm not particularly fond of the count solution either - intersect just seems so much clearer.

Comment: Although `INTERSECT` is not standard SQL so it may not work on all systems.

Comment: @DStanley Actually I believe `intersect` is part of the standards, at least it's part of the BNF grammar for sql 92/99/2003 according to this: http://savage.net.au/SQL/ It's supported in MSSQL/Postgresql/Oracle/DB2 and probably others that I didn't check :)